# Convergence of series that consists of alternating harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a straightforward way to formally show that the following series converges, using the fact that it consists of the alternating harmonic series?

> $1 + 0 - 1/2 + 0 + 1/3 + 0 -1/4 + 0 +1/5 ...$

Or, explicitly,

> $a_{2n-1} = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}} {n}$ and $a_{2n} = 0$.

Comment: Since subseries converge, final series also converges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fairly easy to see that your sum is very similar to

$$1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots$$

We know this series converges.

To be formal, you can prove that the sum of the first $2n-1$ elements of your sequence is equal to the sum of the first $n$ elements of the alternating series above.

---

Purely formally, the proof would go something like:

- You define $S_n = 1-\frac12 + \frac13 - \cdots + (-1)^n\frac1n$.
- From the fact that an alternating series with elements going to $0$ converges, you conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ exists.
- You define $T_n$ as the sum of the first $n$ elements of your sequence.
- You show that $T_2n = S_n$ and $T_{2n-1} = S_n$

You now know that the sequence $\{T_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is the sequence $$S_1, S_1, S_2, S_2, S_3, S_3\dots$$

It should now be straightforward to show that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}T_k = \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$$

hence the original series converges.

Comment: But this only shows that a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums for the above series converges, right? I'm having trouble completing the formalisms.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 If the sequence $$a_1, a_2,a_3\dots$$ converges, then the sequence $$a_1,a_1,a_2,a_2,a_3,a_3,\dots$$ also converges to the same limit.. I would actually say this is *obvious*, but if you want, you can pretty easily show this with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Another way to show it is to show that the sequence is Cauchy, again helping yourself with the known-to-be-convergent alternating sequence.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I did. Thanks again!